# SQL row_number in PostgreSQL below 8.3

Tags: sql, postgresql

Since row_number can't used to

How can I get a row like

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() FROM table
```

Comment: `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(),*FROM table` ?? and `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() FROM table` this will also yields result if you've rows in that table,BTW  what you're trying to get ??

Comment: your question is not clear, explain it properly.

Comment: The duplicate claims to be about `rank` but the answers cover `row_number` too.

Comment: 8.3 is long out of support. You should upgrade to a maintained version **now**.

Comment: Thanks for everyone. Finally I can find a solution CREATE TEMP SEQUENCE foo;

SELECT nextval('foo') can fix this issues